# React Native Codepush - Exclude image assets for certain releases

Tags: code-push, react-native-code-push

Our release bundles are kinda huge (~50MB) and the clients take approx. 1-2 mins to download the update from codepush.

We're mostly just updating the js bundles, is there a way to just delta update the js bundle without re-downloading all image assets?

I've read from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/issues/342%20*here*) that the server performs files diff, but it doesn't seem to work on my case: Logging `RemotePackage.packageSize` from `checkForUpdate` on clients shows the exact size of JS bundle + image assets, despite the fact that I've only changed the JS code.

Is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

The CodePush backend should only serve the full contents up to the point it finishes creating a diff zip. On the backend your package is downloaded, extracted and analyzed for files that are different. Any new/updated/removed files are reconciled, put into another zip and shipped back up to the backend so users get served that instead of the original one you release. If you are seeing the full download, it's either because the backend is still working to process the diffs or there are differences inside your bundle.

I would try to do a release, wait 10 minutes and check to see if it is still downloading the full bundle. If it does, it'd be best to contact support for a deeper dive. As far as I can tell bundle's are processing correctly with next to no errors and running a quick test myself produced the correct results for me.